# python 2.7 string format to decimal as round function

Tags: python, string, format, rounding

I got a problem in string format function which I don't understand. Please help to explain why and how to fix this. thanks.
( python 2.7.3 , [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2 , ubuntu 12.04 x86 )

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.format("%0.{0}f".format(2), 1.135, grouping=True)
'1.14'
>>> locale.format("%0.{0}f".format(2), 1.125, grouping=True)
'1.12'

>>> ("%0.2f")%(1.135)
'1.14'
>>> ("%0.2f")%(1.125)
'1.12'
```

I need the format result to match the round() function

```
>>> round(1.135, 2)
1.14
>>> round(1.125, 2)
1.13
```

Thank everyone.

Comment: Why don't you round it first before printing it?

Comment: So, interestingly in my python3 build, round() returns results that match the string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

That's because rounding is not simply bringing the last digit greater than 5 up, while truncating those lower than 4, since this method would introduce an increase in the expected average of rounded numbers.

The solution is to use [Bankers' Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), that's what you see here.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: why is there a difference between round and format. As far as I've been able to determine it's a combination of the inability to exactly represent decimal numbers in binary format and the rounding algorithm used in both functions.

Comment: Bankers Rounding is very cool -- but that's not what Python 2.7 is doing (at least on my machine!) e.g. I tried 0.605, 0.615, 0.625, 0.635 etc. and only 0.625 fails to round up. The OP's issue was 1/8; this is at 5/8; hmm....